# How to use dl.Overlay with multiple inputs?

Tags: python, dash-leaflet

I tried to apply **dl.Overlay** on multiple inputs (markers and circles) but it shows me an overlay for each input separately.

[image]

I want to have at the end a single overlay for all the markers and the circles around. Any suggestions ?
Here's the code i implemented.

```
import dash_leaflet as dl

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = dl.Map(
[
dl.LayersControl([
dl.Overlay([dl.CircleMarker(center=(48.0073849, 0.1967849), radius=3, color='red'),
dl.Circle(center=(48.0073849, 0.1967849), radius=20000),
dl.CircleMarker(center=(46.0073849, 0.1867849), radius=3, color='red'),
dl.Circle(center=(46.0073849, 0.1867849), radius=20000),
],
name='Exemples', checked=True)
]),
dl.TileLayer(),
],
style={'width': '1000px', 'height': '500px'},
center=[46.232192999999995, 2.209666999999996],
zoom=5
)

if name == 'main':
    app.run_server()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Overlay` component considers each node passed to the `children` prop as a separate overlay. To group multiple objects into a single node, you can use the `LayerGroup` component. Adopting your example, the code would be along the lines of

```
import dash
import dash_leaflet as dl

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = dl.Map([
        dl.LayersControl([
            dl.Overlay(
                dl.LayerGroup([
                    dl.CircleMarker(center=(48.0073849, 0.1967849), radius=3, color='red'),
                    dl.Circle(center=(48.0073849, 0.1967849), radius=20000),
                    dl.CircleMarker(center=(46.0073849, 0.1867849), radius=3, color='red'),
                    dl.Circle(center=(46.0073849, 0.1867849), radius=20000),
                ]), name='Example', checked=True)
        ]), dl.TileLayer(),
    ], style={'width': '1000px', 'height': '500px'}, center=[46.23, 2.21], zoom=5
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```